# Extension and 3rd party app access permissions for Dropbox

Tags: security, permissions, gmail, dropbox, adobe-acrobat

What level of access and permissions does **Dropbox** provide to following 3rd party extensions if a user chooses to integrate their Dropbox accounts with these:

- Adobe Acrobat Reader,
- Google Mail (gmail),
- Microsoft Excel, Powerpoint, Word
- WhatsApp
- Canva
- Slack
- Docusign

...And other 3rd party apps if you feel like adding to the above.

I would like to integrate these with my Dropbox account but unfortunately can’t in good conscience amidst all the data breaches that have happened these days.

Despite my best efforts to find this info, it seems to me that Dropbox and the developers of the 3rd party extensions don’t elaborate on this anywhere in their help pages or in the popup window when providing permission to these apps.

Also, Dropbox makes a distinction between **"extensions"** that are 3rd party apps having a strategic partnership with Dropbox and for lack of more precise expression **"normal" / "vanilla" 3rd party apps** that integrate but don't have a strategic partnership with dropbox. I am at a loss as to what that exactly means (browser integration? verifying privacy standards? financial transactions between Dropbox and these apps?).

Dropbox is vague at every turn about all of the above, so it would be nice to have some clarity. Not sure why Dropbox would want to give permission to any of the above apps beyond the one file the account holder would want to edit or view.

However they apparently do as published in [this help page](https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/third-party/third-party-apps), as developers may choose between following access levels (and I guess this always means full edit permission):

> - Select Access - Provides access to a specific file in your Dropbox account. The app can only access that specific file and only write create and write to a file in that same folder.
> - App Folder - A specific folder in your Dropbox account. The app can only access files in that folder.
> - Full Dropbox - All folders and files in your Dropbox account.

Dropbox or the app developers don't specify anywhere which app has what level access, so if someone (maybe some famous actress) provides unknowingly full account access to e.g. Adobe Acrobat, someday someone in Utah might browse their private wedding pics :-)

Answer (score 1):

Update: I got an answer from the "Advanced Support" team of Dropbox, see below.

> Hi A*****,
>
> Thanks for contacting Dropbox! My name's B*****, and I'm on the
>   Advanced Support team. I'd be happy to help.
>
> Depending on the integration, it may have different levels of access
>   to what data in your account it has access to depending on the
>   function of that integration. We do not have a list of this on our end
>   that we are able to provide.
>
> For a comprehensive overview of how third party integrations have
>   access to your Dropbox account, please visit our Security page here:
>
> https://help.dropbox.com/accounts-billing/security/privacy-policy-faq
>
> Please let me know if you have any other questions.
>
> Regards, B*****

So basically what they are saying is that they are unwilling to provide the information as to what exactly a third party app has access to in a user's account after the user chooses to integrate with the third party application (which Dropbox urges them to do as soon as one tries to view or edit a Word document or an Excel for instance).

Based on this and after reviewing all help information Dropbox provides on their homepage and in their Terms of Use and Privacy Policies, I have to assume that if one integrates their accounts with third party providers such as Adobe or Microsoft to read PDFs or Excel files, **these companies seem to have unlimited, unrestricted access to all files, folders and personal user information linked to the account** and not just the specific files one wants to edit or view.

This is a serious breach of privacy in my personal opinion, as those third party companies are not bound by the same contractual and privacy policy terms one signs with Dropbox. They could even publish openly the contents of anyone's files, as nothing in Dropbox's contractual terms, privacy policies or (even though legally not binding) in the answers to my direct questions seems to forbid them from doing so.